# How do I exit pbcopy in the Mac Terminal?

Tags: macos, shell, unix, terminal

If I just enter `pbcopy` by itself in Terminal, it appears to prompt for user input. I'm assuming that the idea is you enter some input, then exit or end `pbcopy`, and then your input is added to the clipboard, so you can `pbpaste` it or whatever.

I can't figure out how to end `pbcopy`, without using Control-C which kills the process and doesn't save my data to the clipboard.

Still very new to Terminal. Thanks!

Comment: `Ctrl-D` is the usual end of input on the command line, it's the `eof` entry from `stty -a`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For most terminal programs, end of input is triggered by `Ctrl-D`. This is considered the valid conclusion of input from the command.

It could be something else, but the key combination can be read from the output of `stty -a`, which shows an entry: `eof = ^D`, which indicates Ctrl-D is that key combination.

Now programatically, if you're trying to get input into pbcopy, you can do, from a file:

```
cat file | pbcopy
```

or the slightly more 'shell purist' (doesn't waste a process with the cat):

```
pbcopy <file
```

from a bash script, using a here document:

```
pbcopy <<EOM
copy copy copy...
EOM
```