# JetBrains/IntelliJ external tool put text into clipboard

Tags: shell, intellij-idea, clion, jetbrains-ide, pbcopy

I am using "External tools" functionality in CLion (but it's the same for any of the JetBrains IDEs). I want to have a simple tool that will put some link on my clipboard.

[image]

I am on MacOS, so I figured out I can use `pbcopy`. The problem is that when you call `pbcopy {$args}` [the command doesn't stop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28838027/how-do-i-exit-pbcopy-in-the-mac-terminal). Most of the examples I've seen would do `echo $args | pbcopy`, but I can't do that here. I've tried adding a `\n` at the end of the arguments, without success.

I know I could simply create a script that does `echo "$1" | pbcopy` and call it, but I want to share that tool with colleagues so it would be better without asking them to create a script.

Comment: If the idea is for users to ultimately paste the output into the IDE, maybe these plugins can help: https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/15539-external-tools-text-replace or https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/15539-external-tools-text-replace

Comment: @Koyasha the goal of the tool is to generate a url that can be easily sent to other colleagues through the internal messaging app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `bash` in "Program" field and `-c "echo \"Hello world\" | pbcopy"` in "Arguments" field for it.